# Bending a ping-pong racket

Tags: mesh, faces, subdivision-surface

I want to bend a ping-ping racket.

[image]

I tried to use a curve modifier and I faced a problem which I think it's  solvable only in Python scripting. I hope there is an easier solution without any programming involved.

The curve modifier, to make a smooth bending, requires a lot of cross edge loops. It's easy to get them for Mesh objects like a cube or a cylinder using the tool loop cut and slide.
Tutorials about bending, I have found, don't discuss effective ways to doing so for complex objects, created with extruding a bezier curve.

I created a half of the contour of my racked with a bezier curve, mirrored it and extruded. Back and front sides are covered with triangles. I tried to beatify, poke triangulation, etc, but I cannot get faces in form of wide trapezoids automatically.

Subdividing pocked ngon is not good. It enforces to make a lot of triangles I don't need. Such triangulation doesn't give equal distribution. Some places has a lot of faces but others don't.

Here it my desirable ngon trapezoidation (Top view)

```
    ______ 
   /______\
  /________\
  |________|
   \______/
      ||
      ||
```

An idea about limitation of an triangle edge also looks promising, but I wonder why there is no such parameter for the triangulate operation.
I would get a lot of small triangles, but at least vertex density of the surface would be homogeneous.

Comment: What is purpose of this model and why not quads?

Comment: It should be a 3d printed sculpture.  This is my first day of using blender. How to use quads?

Comment: I don't have experience with 3D printing, but as far as I know proper topology is crucial for it. I'm trying to model this one now and I'll post answer in a while.

Answer (score 2):

This case is pretty basic modeling stuff, so I will not go deeper in simple details and just show you an overview not to write full blown tutorial here (it's not place for this). If this is your first day you will need to know some starter pack things like:

- **Edge Loops** and **Edge Flow** in general (tris, quads, ngons, poles and such),
- creating, joining, cutting (**Loop Cuts**), extruding faces,
- adding simple modifiers (**Mirror**, **Subdivision Surface**, **Curve**).

Everything is here, on Blender Stack Exchange as well as on YouTube or any other place with Blender resources (there is topic with them here too).

> I'm trying here some new answer technique, so be gentle. I'll expand
>   this answer as much as OP will need it.

### Overview:

[image: overview]

1. Start with simple **Plane** at extrude one edge along green curve 9 times (to get 10 faces).
2. Add **Mirror Modifier** with **Clipping** checked.
3. Fill in faces in the middle of paddle (I don't know how this rubber surface is called).
4. Extrude bottom face to have a handle.
5. Add **Subdivision Surface Modifier**.
6. Select all and extrude it to gave depth to paddle.
7. Add **Loop Cuts** along green curve (the same from first step) and the short one at the bottom.
8. Add **Bezier Curve**.
9. Add **Curve modifier** for paddle. Important! It should be above **Subdivision Surface**.
10. Move the paddle along **Curve** to adjust it.
11. Edit **Curve** to give it bend.

In the blend file, on layer 2 you have 3 models of paddle to study them.

[image]

### Blend File:

Temporary link (Blend Exchange giving some error with URL):

[paddle.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwQPHxVeoc90VkRLQUcxcWd4eDg)