# How to bend the shape

Tags: mesh

I have made the leaf shape and want to bend with the reference image.

[image]

I have on the proportional editing on also. But the problem its not bending its moving from the place.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Later i have to extrude and offset.

Any suggestion and help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Topology

First of all if you need to bend a mesh you will need proper quad based topology. This will allow also to add **Subsurf Modifier** later on if needed.

Here is an example how it can look:

[image: topology]

You can make it as you want, just keep quads.

### Bending:

In this method I'm gonna use **Bezier Curve** and **Curve Modifier**.

Add to your scene **Bezier Curve** and place it accordingly to your leaf mesh. For example:

[image: placed]

After that add **Curve Modifier** to leaf mesh and select **Bezier Curve** as **Object**.

[image: gif]

Now you can move leaf mesh or in **Edit Mode** change **Bezier Curve** shape as needed.

### Blend file:

[image]

You can check my answer here for similar method:
 [Bending a ping-pong racket](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75427/bending-a-ping-pong-racket/75432#75432)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Simple Deform Modifier to bend objects.

Make sure that your mesh has some subdivisions.

[image]

Add an empty.

[image]

On the mesh you want to deform add a Simple Deform Modifier, set it to bend mode and have the axis for the Origin be the Empty.

[image]

Then rotate the empty so that you get the curvature on the desired angle:

[image]

You can determine the angle for the deformation by changing the Deform Angle on the modifier.

[image]